# How to avoid use of the temporary table in my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to keep both `tblPurchase` and `tblProductStock` tables. My SQL is below:

```
SELECT MAX(ItemName) ItemName,
   ItemCode,
   SUM(Quantity) Quantity
INTO #tmp
FROM tblPurchase
GROUP BY itemCode;

UPDATE tblProductStock
SET Quantity=#tmp.Quantity
FROM #tmp WHERE tblProductStock.ItemCode=#tmp.ItemCode

INSERT INTO tblProductStock
    (
        ItemName,
        ItemCode,
        Quantity
    )
SELECT  ItemName, ItemCode, Quantity FROM #tmp WHERE ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM tblProductStock)

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

Comment: You did not post a stored procedure - only a short script. And you seem to dance around the same issue over multiple threads. I suggest you have been given poor advice and suggestions - first and foremost is the use of a pattern that many apply blindly without thinking. That is the pattern of <select into temp table>, <do minimal thing with temp table>, <select result from temp table>. In addition, it seems you have taken the wrong path. Why would you need to repeatedly calculate balances for everything in your stock table and then apply (i.e., store) those balances.

Comment: OK @SMor. Can you please tell me how to resolve this problem. I don't want to delete data and table.

Comment: Aside from Smor's very relevant comments **why** do you want to avoid a temp table? What do you think it will improve?

Comment: tblPurchase and tblProductStock tables are permanent tables in my database. i want to keep tables and data. can you tell me how to write this without temp

Comment: You can just use a CTE... twice... but why??? And I see from your other questions that you've also tried an incremental trigger - which is most likely a better solution anyway (assuming you have to do things this way) - what was wrong with that approach?You will find on this site that you will get much better answers if you provide more context for what you are trying to accomplish. If people understand the bigger picture they can provide better advice.

Comment: Thank Dale K. I will try to use  CTE